# How to append a word to the beginning of the url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, append, hyperlink, routes

I want to create routes that are like googles (mail.google.com) inside of something like (google.com/mail)

how could I, for example, make it posts.example.com instead of example.com/posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want.  If you just want posts.example.com to take someone to example.com/posts you can use a named route, otherwise look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Comment: Isn't this just as easy as having your hosting provider manage a subdomain, and then set posts#index as your root?  I must be missing something--that often happens...perhaps you mean per controller having a different subdomain?